# How to make quick backup of untracked files which I want to delete by git clean?

Tags: git, bash, shell, backup

I have a lot of untracked files. I am pretty sure that most of them I can delete, however... you know, backup could be helpful ;)

What you are doing in similar situation?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following command will create a tar archive in your home directory of all of the untracked (and not ignored) files in your directory:

```
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 tar rvf ~/backup-untracked.tar
```

If you're going to use this technique, check carefully that `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` on its own produces the list of files you expect!

A few notes on this solution might be in order:

- I've used `-z` to get `git ls-files` to output the list of files with `NUL` (a zero byte) as the separator between files, and the `-0` parameter to `xargs` tells it to consider `NUL` to be the separator between the parameters it reads from standard input.  This is a standard trick to deal with the possibility that a filename might contain a newline, since the only two bytes that aren't allowed in filenames on Linux are `NUL` and `/`.
- If you have a huge number of untracked files then `xargs` will run the `tar` command more than once, so it's important that I've told `tar` to append files (`r`) rather than create a new archive (`c`), otherwise the later invocations of `tar` will overwrite the archive created just before.

Comment: hint: it should be --others instead of --other

Comment: For compressed archives you can use the -T option.  `tar -T - -cvzf backup-untracked.tar.gz`

Answer (score 7):

Generally if they are ever going to be useful, then you should be checking them in!  If you don't need them right now, then check them in and remove them!  IE, track them as deleted files.  That way you can always recover them later if you decide you do need them.

Remember, a fundamental rule of using a version control system is "track **everything**".  Small changes, broken changes (in a branch), etc.  You never know when you might need those files or changes again, so use your VC system to make sure you can't lose them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), but you have to track them first. If they’re explicitly ignored, they won’t get added.

```
git add .
git stash
```

Now all the untracked files are stashed away and gone from the working directory. If this was incorrect, use `git stash pop`, add and commit the ones you want to keep, and repeat.

Comment: I think that `git stash` would also save full state of working area... well, at least of tracked files.

Comment: I think it's implied that the working area is clean save for untracked files.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to make a complete local copy of your git repository (including .git) and there delete all what 'git ls-files' shows resp. all tracked files.

Something like:

```
cd copy_of_repository
git ls-files | xargs printf "rm \"%s\"\n" > delete_tracked_files.sh.txt
```

Review **delete_tracked_files.sh.txt**, change name to **delete_tracked_files.sh** and execute it.

You may also want to disconnect the copy from the remote, just to prevent unintentional pulls or pushes.

```
git remote remove origin
```